# Enumerating namedtuples

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of namedtuples of the following form

```
from collections import namedtuple
item = namedtuple('item', 'position state')
```

I'd like to create the list so that the position field the item corresponds to the position of the item in the list.

So far I've tried:

```
l = [item(position=i, state=0)]*10
```

However this produces 10 items which look like this:

```
item(position=(0, item(position=0, state=0))
```

Could someone explain what's going on, and if there's a nice (one-line maybe) way of doing what I want.

Comment: What is `i`, in this case?

Comment: @thefourtheye just a number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
l = [item(i, 0) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: what was going on with what I tried: why did I get that output?

Comment: because the multiplication (*) mean replicate/repeat it's like doing: `[item(0, 0) for i in range(10)]`

Answer (score 3):

This should work (too slow - kudos to NPE :p):

```
l = [item(position=i, state=0) for i in range(10)]
```